# How to update row by id in jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, crud

I am trying to update a row in mysql database by the id of the row, but it isn't inputting the new values into the database. I have tried to tinker with the code but I just can't figure it out. I test by passing the data as json via postman. Can you spot what is wrong with my code? Code files below (update sql script in the jdbc is probably most relevant):

Repo:

JDBC repo:

```
@Repository
public class QuizRepositoryJDBC implements QuizRepository{
private static final String UPDATE_QUESTION = "UPDATE Quiz SET type=?, level=?, choiceNum=?, question=?, choiceA=?, choiceB=?, " +
        "choiceC=?, choiceD=?, correct=?, hint=? WHERE ID=?";

    private static final String DELETE_QUESTION_BY_ID = "DELETE FROM Quiz WHERE ID=?";

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public QuizRepositoryJDBC(JdbcTemplate aTemplate){
        jdbcTemplate = aTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public QuizDTO updateQuestion(QuizDTO quizDTO) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_QUESTION, quizDTO.getID(), quizDTO.getType(), quizDTO.getLevel(), quizDTO.getChoiceNum(),quizDTO.getQuestion(), quizDTO.getChoiceA(),
                quizDTO.getChoiceB(), quizDTO.getChoiceC(), quizDTO.getChoiceD(), quizDTO.getCorrect(), quizDTO.getHint());
        return quizDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteQuestion(int id) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_QUESTION_BY_ID, id);
        return "Deleted question with id:" + id;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class QuizController {

    private QuizRepository quizRepo;

    @Autowired
    public QuizController(QuizRepository pRepo) {
        quizRepo = pRepo;
    }

    @PutMapping("/adminupdate")
    public QuizDTO updateQuestion(@RequestBody QuizDTO quizDTO) {

        return quizRepo.updateQuestion(quizDTO);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/admindelete/{id}")
    public String deleteQuestion(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return quizRepo.deleteQuestion(id);
    }

}
```

JSON that I pass into postman:

```
{
"id": 104,
"type":"epidemics",
"level":1,
"choiceNum":4,
"question":"another one question",
"choiceA": "no1",
"choiceB":"yes2",
"choiceC":"no3",
"choiceD":"yes4",
"correct":"no1",
"hint":"second answer"
}
```

Comment: Nothing immediately jumps out. Your code only deletes and updates existing rows; nothing in your paste could ever _add_ a row. Perhaps the answer is the trivial one: You have no rows in the DB, therefore, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` run without failure, and... do nothing. Because that's by definition what they do when there are no rows. Just.. return. silently.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the json that I pass into the controller. Does that change your view?

Comment: No, the content of the JSON seems entirely unrelated. Did you understand a word of my comment? All we need to know is: Is there an actual row with the actual ID you are using for the `?` in `DELETE ... WHERE ID =? `

Comment: It feels like you think an SQL `UPDATE` commands creates a new row in the database. It doesn't.

Comment: Look for the `INSERT` SQL usage